# sleep fails for OSX command

Tags: bash, macos

When I try to run the "sleep" command I get the message `usage: sleep seconds`.
My command:

```
for ((i=100;i<=105;i++)); do sleep 2 echo "hi"; done
```

and even just trying:
`sleep 20s echo "hi"` returns the same.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` and `echo` are separate commands, so you have to separate them with a semicolon: `sleep 2; echo "hi"`

```
for ((i=100;i<=105;i++)); do sleep 2; echo "hi"; done
```